# MASM32 function that multiplies two double precision numbers and returns it

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, masm32, sse2

I need to write function that should use SSE2 to convert radians to degrees.
This is for assignment. I have no idea how to do it.

_180_PI is number equal to 180/3.141592...
My function needs to just return `return rad * _180_PI`

This function is in dll and this is how its declaration:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall RadToDegAsm(double rad);
```

I have:

```
.DATA
    _180_PI dq 57.2957795130823208767981548141

.CODE

RadToDegAsm PROC rad: QWORD
    movupd xmm0, rad
    mulsd xmm0, _180_PI
    ;I need to somehow return it
RadToDegAsm ENDP
```

Main question:
**How to return 64bit(double) contents of xmm0 register so that it works with given declaration?**

Comment: You should use `movsd` to load the argument and you are missing a `ret` at the end, unless `ENDP` puts it there for you. Otherwise it should be fine, what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Is the C code built as 64-bit or 32-bit code?

Comment: It is x86. And I didn't finish that function because I don't know how to return double from asm __stdcall function. Normal 32bit numbers are returned in eax. But double (64bit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working:

```
.DATA
    _180_PI dq 57.2957795130823208767981548141
.CODE

RadToDegAsm PROC rad: QWORD
    LOCAL returnValue: QWORD
    movsd xmm0, rad
    mulsd xmm0, _180_PI
    movsd returnValue, xmm0
    fld return
    ret
RadToDegAsm ENDP
```

double value is returned via floating point registers (fld) instruction.